# Is there a way to determine in the constructor of a class if an instance is being deserialized?

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization

Lets say I have business class:

```
public class Foo
{
   public int Prop1 {get;set;}
   public int Prop2 {get;set;}

   public Foo(int prop1, int prop2)
   {
      this.Prop1 = prop1;
      this.Prop2 = prop2;
   }

   public Foo()
   {
     throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
}
```

The business class is only valid if both properties are set. Therefore I could ensure implementing the parameterless constructor and throw a NotImplementedException if someone tries to instanciate the class with the parameterless constructor.

But now I want to be able to serialize/deserialize my class. For the deserilization process I need the default constructor, which musn't throw the NotImplementedExeption anymore.

Is there a way to find out whether a create an instance of my class with the default constructor or whether the object is being deserialized?

Let's assume I have no valid default values for both properties.

How could I solve this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide the default constructor using protected modifier.

[Read More](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182343.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Binary deserialization will NOT call any constructors, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement `ISerializable` then you will have the deserialisation happen through the constructor you need to use for that.

If you implement `IXmlSerializable` and the serialisation is by XmlSerialization, then you will have the deserialisation happen through the `ReadXml` method defined by that interface.

If you implement `IDeserializationCallback`, then you will have your implementation of `OnDeserialization` called **after** the object is constructed. That might be too late for your purposes, but if its enough, then it is probably the easiest to add to an already-existing class.